# Print out a content with the css style using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a specific page the container some information with a specific design

this design exist in a separate page `print.css`

I want to print this page with the same style and this page containe an image also

```js
function printContent() {
    var divContents = document.getElementById("terms").innerHTML;
    var a = window.open('', '', 'height=1000, width=1000');
    a.document.write('<html>');
    a.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"print.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\"/>");
    a.document.write('<body >');
    a.document.write(divContents);
    a.document.write('</body></html>');
    a.document.close();
    a.focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        a.print();
    }, 1000);
    a.print();
}
```

```css
p {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container header .top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2c2a6b;
}

.container header .top h1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #2c2a6b;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.container header .top .print-header {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
}

.container header .top .print-header h2{
    color: #2c2a6b;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.container header .print-subheader {
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .top img {
    width: 50px;
}

.container main .print-content .top h3 {
    color: #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .content{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container main .print-content .content .inner-box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container main .print-content .content .inner-box p{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container" id="terms">
        <header>
            <div class="top">
                <h1>قطاع السياحة</h1>
                <div class="print-header">
                    <img src="images/title-icon.png" alt="title">
                    <h2> اصدار رخصة الإيواء السياحي</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="print-subheader">
                <h2>الحصول على رخصة استثمار (المستثمر الاجنبي)</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="print-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <img src="images/terms.png" alt="terms">
                    <h3>الاشتراطات العامة</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn-print" onclick="printContent()" value="Print">
</body>
```

the problem is that the image and the style don't appear after i click the print button

after a search i found that i should put a timeout, and i should include the print.css file with media print but after all that the problem still exist i can't print the page with the image and the css style anyone can help please

Comment: When [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) is called after the page has been parsed, it cretes a new document, which wipes out all the code on the page, only what is written with `d.w` is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *seems* like an overly complicated solution to a really simply requirement, but perhaps there are details you've left out of the question.

It seems like you're including the CSS file dynamically just for printing purposes, but CSS already has a feature for this. I recommend removing all of your JavaScript, and instead wrapping your CSS in a **print media query**, like so:

```css
@media print {
    p {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    /* the rest of your styles here */
}
```

Simply include these print styles with the rest of your page's CSS and the browser will take care of applying them for the **print** media.

If you absolutely *must* do this with JavaScript, you're going to need to wait until the stylesheet is finished loading. You can do that by creating the element, attaching an event listener for the `onload` event, then appending it to the DOM.

Something like:

```js
let styles = document.createElement('link');
styles.addEventListener('load', function(){
    window.print();
});
styles.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
styles.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
styles.setAttribute('href', 'print.css');
document.head.appendChild(styles);
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer that cover what I need, Thanks @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="terms">
        <header>
            <div class="top">
                <h1>قطاع السياحة</h1>
                <div class="print-header">
                    <img src="images/title-icon.png" alt="title">
                    <h2> اصدار رخصة الإيواء السياحي</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="print-subheader">
                <h2>الحصول على رخصة استثمار (المستثمر الاجنبي)</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="print-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <img src="images/terms.png" alt="terms">
                    <h3>الاشتراطات العامة</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
  <button onclick="window.print();" class="noPrint">
Print Me
</button>
</body>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
  .noPrint{
    display:none;
  }
}
h1{
  color:#f6f6;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container header .top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2c2a6b;
}

.container header .top h1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #2c2a6b;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.container header .top .print-header {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
}

.container header .top .print-header h2{
    color: #2c2a6b;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.container header .print-subheader {
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .top img {
    width: 50px;
}

.container main .print-content .top h3 {
    color: #2c2a6b;
}

.container main .print-content .content{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container main .print-content .content .inner-box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container main .print-content .content .inner-box p{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

By adding the  class="noPrint" you can remove what you dont want printed out!
Let me know if this is what you had in mind

here is a [codepen.io link](https://codepen.io/jankees/pen/OJxbGZN)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load the image via js?

or is that the picture?

terms.png

This should be displayed, but you can also load it separately via js and adjust it in print.css.

```
a.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./print.css">'); //loads the style

document.write('<img src="./images/terms.png"> //or
document.write('<img src="./images/terms.png" style="style for the picture">
```

Comment: oh and if it is not displayed it might be because of the z-index?

Comment: you can also hide in a separate css everything you don't need - display: none;